# Call a Context within a class for a different activity

Tags: java, android

I am checking for SEND_SMS permission within a class:

```
public class SendSms extends Activity{
    int requestPerm;

    private void checkPermissionSms(){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                          requestPerm);                                 //If we don't have the permission, request it here
        }
    }
```

But at checkSelPermission, it needs a context but I'm not sure what context it needs(not even too sure what Context for checkSelfPermission)
I am following:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#java

The above method is called like so:

```
public static void sendSms(String message){
   // Intent calledSendSMS = getIntent();
    //String message = calledSendSMS.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
 //   PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, new Intent(this,SendSms.class),0);
    SendSms checkPerm = new SendSms();
    SmsManager sendTheMessage = SmsManager.getDefault();
    String phoneNumber = "5556";
    checkPerm.checkPermissionSms();
    sendTheMessage.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null,message,null,null);
}
```

And this Method is called from another activity. 
I did put in "this" but then I get the following error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)' on a null object reference
                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.checkPermission(ContextWrapper.java:724)
                      at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ContextCompat.java:430)
                      at com.example.android.footysortit.SendSms.checkPermissionSms(SendSms.java:17)
```

Really all I want to do is check for permission and request it if needed.

Edit: If I add the check permissions within an actual activity and use "this" it works just fine.
So how do I get it to pass the activity data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
SendSms checkPerm = new SendSms();
```

To:

```
SendSms checkPerm = new SendSms(this);
```

SendSms class - you need to create constuctor of the class

```
public class SendSms extends Activity {

private Activity mActivity;
private int requestPerm;

public SendSms(Activity mActivity) {
    this.mActivity = mActivity;

}

private void checkPermissionSms() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, requestPerm);
        //If we don't have the permission, request it here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But then how would I call checkPermissionSms in a static method, because I use a static method(the one I put in my question) to call checkPermissionsSms>

Comment: declare Activity and int as static

Comment: Thank you, always forget about this stuff